# Error inflating class fragment with Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-emulator

Very easy demo followed by Google Api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**Location.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class Location extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
    }
}
```

a

**This is my Mainfest ...All of this follow by google Api.65465465465465465464***
55444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssadasdsad

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ie.wit.bookbank"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
 <uses-permission android:name="ie.wit.bookbank.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<!-- camera -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<!-- map -->
<permission
    android:name="ie.wit.bookbank.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission            android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBrbh8Oa3az6rjBtcYUEZfQLrkKiOR5vUU" />

    <activity
        android:name="ie.wit.bookbank.Newbook"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ie.wit.bookbank.Location"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Is that I add  googl- play- severir wrong ?

Comment: Try many methods but doesn't work. Who can help me ?

Comment: post your `Manifest.xml` file.

Comment: @user3396562 try as per my answer and correct as my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logcat clearly said

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in
>   your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.
>
> Expected 4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the  element:

**Add the Google Play services version to your app's manifest**

> Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the
>   following declaration within the element. This embeds the version of
>   Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

You need to add `<meta-data>` under `<application>` tag into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
....<application>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

This is because latest google play services requires a version name, which is to be mentioned using `<meta-data .. />` inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

and also change this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: After that I have 03-08 18:08:54.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-08 18:08:54.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ie.wit.bookbank-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ie.wit.bookbank-2, /system/lib]]

Comment: Did I miss some thing ?

Comment: @user3396562 have you added `google_play_services_lib` into your project? and also post your manifest.xml file

Comment: @user3396562 i got your issue. i think you write wrong in your `android:name="com.google.android.gms.SupportMapFragment` **correct** like `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`. it's typo.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your
>   app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected
>   4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within
>   the  element:

Make sure you have the updated google play services which is rev 15

Add the below as a child of application tag and it should work

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

You also need to change

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

to

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: After that I have    03-08 18:08:54.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public 03-08 18:08:54.016: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ie.wit.bookbank-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ie.wi‌​t.bookbank-2, /system/lib]]

Comment: Did I forget import some things ?

Comment: have you referenced google play services library project in your andorid project